# Why can't the Rust compiler infer the type when calling parse?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a sum calculator in Rust, but I found that the Rust compiler can't infer a type in some cases. Here is the code.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).unwrap();
    let sum = s.split_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|c| c.parse().ok())
        .fold(0, |a, b| a + b);
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

The Rust compiler told me:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |         .fold(0, |a, b| a + b);
  |                      ^ consider giving this closure parameter a type
```

However, IntelliJ IDEA infers the type is `i32`.

If we type `let a = 0;`, the type of `a` is `i32` by default. I guess IDEA infer the type of initial value `0` of the `fold` function is `i32`, so the `sum` type in the fourth line can be inferred to `i32` and `c` should be parsed to `i32` on the next line. But why can't the Rust compiler infer the type?

I  have also tried to declare the `sum` type in the fourth line, and the Rust compiler give me the same error. Why can't the Rust compiler infer the type in this case?

If I declare the `parse()` type or do as compiler told me, then it compiles.

Comment: IIRC IDEAs code does not rely on the rust compiler at all. Therefore if you encounter an error, always use rustc as a reference, never your IDE warnings/errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specifically mentioned in the [documentation for `parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse) (emphasis mine):

> Because `parse` is so general, it can cause problems with type inference. As such, parse is one of the few times you'll see the syntax affectionately known as the 'turbofish': `::<>`. This helps the inference algorithm understand specifically which type you're trying to parse into.
>
> **`parse` can parse any type that implements the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait**.

There are many [implementors of `FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html), which is why you have to tell Rust exactly which type you want to parse from the `String`.

Comment: Note also that `i32` implements both [`Add<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Add%3Ci32%3E) and [`Add<&i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27a%20i32%3E), so knowing that `a` is `i32` still leaves two possibilities for the type of `b`: it could be either `i32` or `&i32`. That's why you need to tell the compiler which one to take.